# SOAP Req works in console but in dev/prod - Socketerror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, bing-api, savon

I have a SOAP request (I'm using the Savon gem) that works perfectly in the console but when I try to integrate it into my Rails app, I get the following "SocketError":

**getaddrinfo: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.**

pointing to the @response line in my controller...

search_controller.rb

```
#Start Bing Code
client = Savon.client("https://adcenter.api.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/v8/CampaignManagement/CampaignManagementService.svc?wsdl")
@response = client.request :v8, :get_campaigns_by_account_id do
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:v8"] = "https://adcenter.microsoft.com/v8"
  soap.header = "<v8:UserName>######</v8:UserName><v8:Password>######</v8:Password><v8:DeveloperToken>######</v8:DeveloperToken>"
  soap.body = "<v8:AccountId>######</v8:AccountId>"
end
@responsehash = @response.to_hash
```

In my console I end up with a hash that I can parse for the values I need in the view.  I can't find anything in the bing docs or SO and this really has me stumped.

Sidenote - if you are familiar with Savon you may see that I'm using v1. I'm forced to because the adwords gem I am using depends on v1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Used an old WSDL from the docs...

Should be -

https://**adcenterapi.microsoft.com**